# Plugin de previsualización de thumbnail no funciona

Tags: jquery

Necesito un plugin de **jquery** que haga una previsualización del tamaño completo de las thumbnails, he encontrado uno que hace justo lo que quiero.

http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar (no carga la previsualización al poner el ratón sobre la imagen).

Este es su código.

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;



    /* END CONFIG */
    $("#imagenesthumbnails a.preview").hover(function(e){
        //  $("body").css('background-color','green');
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("#imagenesthumbnails a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){

    imagePreview();
});
```

Para comprobar si añade o no algo a la etiqueta body he puesto esta linea que he comentado

```
$("body").css('background-color','green');
```

y funciona correctamente.

**PARTE DEL CODIGO HTML(LARAVEL)**

El código es demasiado largo por lo que no puedo ponerlo todo, pero pongo la parte a donde hace referencia el código de arriba, salvo la etiqueta body.

```
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>

                                <tr class="text-uppercase">
                                    <th>Imagen</th>
                                     <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Eliminar</th>

                                </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                @foreach($listapost as $post)
                                <tr data-identificador="{{$contador}}">
                                    <td id="imagenesthumbnails">
                                        <a href="{{url('/ima/posts').'/'.$post->imagen}}" class="preview">
                                            <img src="{{url('/ima/posts').'/'.$post->imagen}}" alt ="id {{$post->id}}" width="50px" >
                                        </a>
                                    </td>



                                    <td>
    <a href="{{route('admin.posts.edit',array($post->id))}}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
</td>
                                    <td>


                                        {!! Form::open(array('route' =>array('admin.posts.destroy',$post->id),'method'=>'delete')) !!}
                                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash eliminarpost" value ="DEL" >
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Si queires que te ayude más gente monta todo los elementos en un JsFiddle y pon aquí el enlace.

Comment: Sería mejor si compartieses el código generado